# Android SeekBar strange behaviour

Tags: android, seekbar

I have a default SeekBar in Android with 3 possible values: 0,1,2 (left, middle, right).

But it takes some value only when finger is exactly on the point(corresponding to the value) or to the **right** of it. If the finger is even 1 pixel left of the point, seekbar takes previous value.

I want it to take value when finger is **near** the point.
My explanation skill is very poor, so see the picture:
[image: drawing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using 3 points isn't enough, why not add more points and map back to your 3? e.g.

```
private static final double RATIOS = new double[]{ .33, 66, 100 }
private static final int FAKED_POINTS = new int[]{ 0, 50, 100 }

private void setupSeekBar() {
    // Your normal setup
    seekBar.setMax(100);
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    if(!fromUser) // We only want to do this when the user changes the values
        return;

    for(int i = 0; i < RATIOS.length; i++){
        if(progress <= RATIOS[i]){
            onRealProgressChanged(i);

            seekBar.setProgress(FAKED_POINTS[i]); //  This way it always stays on our 3 faked points
        }
    }
}

private void onRealProgressChanged(int realProgress){
    // Deal with the real changed value (being 0, 1, or 2)
}
```

If you need even more fine-tuning, you can scale that up another order of magnitude.

Not very clean or pretty, but should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a custom Seekbar view library that could help you.

Please use it and if you like it, share it!

Add this line to your gradle file in the app module

```
compile 'mx.segundamano.doubleseekbarview:seekbars:1.0.2'
```

and add this to your build.gradle project level file

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url  "http://dl.bintray.com/segundamanomx/maven" 
    }
}
```

Inside are two custom view, one with one selector and the other with two selectors.

Enjoy it ;)

Comment: Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: mx.segundamano.doubleseekbarview:seekbars:1.0.1
Could you please upload it to github?

Comment: @Egor, sure, this is the github project https://github.com/SegundamanoMX/Seekbars